# send a file to multiple clients using TCP socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, filestream

I'm developing a web application which waits for N (say, around 5) users to connect to a webservice via a TCP socket. The server keeps track of the number of sockets connected, and once it reaches N he then sends a (single) file, say up to 2MB, to all of them simultaneously. The emphasis here is on timing - they should all receive the file at the same time, rather than one after the other.

As a newbie to c# and socket programming, I wish to know what would be the best approach in this case? 
I thought of the following: 
The server (asynchronously) receives socket connections and once it reaches N, loops through all of the bytes in the file, and on each iteration sends a single Kbyte (or maybe less?) to each one of the clients connected - this, in my opinion, is the closest way to sending a file simultaneously.

I'm kind of confused about how to implement this. 
Any help would be great.
Thanks

EDIT:
by receiving at the same time I meant, technically, that I don't want the server sending the file to the first client, then to the second, then to the third etc, but rather send it to all of them at once, once it's out of the server, it's out of my hands! Assuming there are no network problems, and the clients are all very near (physically), they should receive the file more or less at the same time.
maybe the solution is simpler than I thought...

Comment: I think you are looking for multicasting.

Comment: No, likely NOT. Multicasting has serious infrastructure requirements and DOES NOT WORK ON THE INTERNET. On company networks it floods the network unless you use ICMP. I like it a lot, but recommending multicast based on this information is gross neglect and borders not having a clue about networks. This likely works in a non-multicast infrastructur (most companies are as well as the internet).

Comment: "They should all receive the file at the same time" - you are thinking of sending blocks of data, but could you explain more about what you consider "receiving a file at the same time"? Perhaps some context info.

Comment: So if one of the clients doesn't receive some of the data, either because it's slow or because it's malicious, you want to delay data to the other clients? Do you have any control over the clients? Can they implement an acknowledgement protocol? (Your idea about sending in small chunks makes no sense and won't work. It will just make performance stink as you'll be filling your own send buffers slowly and causing segmentation delays.)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis,@David Schwarz, by receiving at the same time I meant,  technically, that I don't want the server sending the file to the first client, then to the second, then to the third etc, but rather send it to all of them at once, once it's out of the server, it's out of my hands! Assuming there are no network problems, the file should reach all of them roughly at the same time!

Comment: @Daniel: Then just try to send to all of them as quickly as you can. Don't do silly things like using small buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already plan to accept socket connections asynchronously and since a callback occurs on a separate thread, you could simply have an async callback that:

- accepts the incoming socket connection
- calls BeginAccept() again (on the listening socket)
- sends the file
- closes the connection (of the previously accepted socket)

If multiple clients connect at once, this will result in multiple threads sending the file concurrently, and almost at the same time.

Your file may be accessed by multiple threads at once, so you'll have to for instance open it with `FileShare.Read`.

Hope this helps, I ignored the "N simultaneous clients" as I understand this is not really a requirement.